# Is it possible to reduce the load time of 'The Last of Us' on PS3?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive, the-last-of-us

I got a new PS3 (500GB) 2 days ago, which came with *The Last of Us* on Disc. But I must say this game takes lots of time to load.

First time it took horribly too much time, next time onwards it took less time to load but still it is too much.

Is there any ways to load this game faster? Can this be installed to the 500GB HDD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will the PSN Download of GTA5 onto a solid state drive perform better than the standard disc install?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141430/will-the-psn-download-of-gta5-onto-a-solid-state-drive-perform-better-than-the-s)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no option to install the Last of Us on to the PS3 hard drive which means as long as you have the game on disc you have no options to reduce loading times.

If you have a digital copy of the game and also have Solid state hard drive installed in your PS3 you can significantly reduce the load times by around 1 minute,  see youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6wfYnYCJQI).